# Why <%if cars="Volvo" then Response.Write("checked")%>

Tags: asp-classic

I am kind a new to ASP and i see an example but can't figure out why using 

<%if cars="Volvo" then Response.Write("checked")%>

Code:->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<%
dim cars
cars=Request.Form("cars")
%> 
<body>
<form action="demo_radiob.asp" method="post">
<p>Please select your favorite car:</p>

<input type="radio" name="cars"
<%if cars="Volvo" then Response.Write("checked")%>
value="Volvo">Volvo</input>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="cars"
<%if cars="Saab" then Response.Write("checked")%>
value="Saab">Saab</input>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="cars"
<%if cars="BMW" then Response.Write("checked")%>
value="BMW">BMW</input>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<%
if cars<>"" then
Response.Write("<p>Your favorite car is: " & cars & "</p>")
end if
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is being used to make the radio button checked when output as HTML.

Here is more detailed explaination of the checked attribute - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp

The response.write is printing out the string.  Again here is a link to a more detailed explaination - http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_write_response.asp

HTH

Wade

Comment: Np, don't hesitate to ask me any other questions.